# Why does "5 in range(5,6) in [range(5,6)]" returns True?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I happened to notice that `5 in range(5,6) in [range(5,6)]` returns `True`.
Can someone explain to me what's the logic behind this ? isn't this line equivalent to `True in [range(5,6)]`? why not? and how does it really work?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python allows you to "chain" comparison operators ([from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

And `in` counts as a comparison operator in the above quote. So the expression is equivalent to:

```py
5 in range(5, 6) and range(5, 6) in [range(5, 6)]
```

Which is `True`, because `5` is in that range, and `range(5, 6)` is in that list.

Answer (score 3):

Two things are coming into play when you do `5 in range(5,6) in [range(5,6)]`:

1. How two `in` operations work together.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

That is, `x in y in z` is equivalent to `x in y and y in z`.

2. `5 in range(5,6)` is `True`, but why `range(5,6) in [range(5,6)]` is also `True`?

Again, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).

So what's really happening in the second part of the line is, really, `any(x is range(5,6) or x == range(5,6) for x in [range(5,6)])`. Thus, `True`.